# ¿Cómo mostrar números pares en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los números pares existentes hasta el número indicado a través de un cuadro de diálogo, usando un bucle `for` y un `prompt`?

Tengo algo como esto pero no me funciona.

```js
let paresalerta = prompt(`Indica hasta que número quieres ver : `);

let pares = [''];

if (paresalerta == null || paresalerta == '') {
  alert('Debes introducir un valor');
}

for (let i = 0; i < pares.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML = pares;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="salida" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor que interesa es `paresalerta`

```js
let paresalerta = prompt(`Indica hasta que número quieres ver : `);

let pares = [''];

if (paresalerta == null || paresalerta == '') {

  alert('Debes introducir un valor');
}

for (let i = 0; i <= paresalerta; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(i);
  }

}
```

Y si quieres validar incluso el numero ingresado debes usar let i = 0; i `<=` paresalerta; i++

Answer (score 0):

Creo que querías hacer algo así:

```js
let paresalerta = prompt(`Indica hasta que número quieres ver : `);

let pares = [];

if (paresalerta == null || paresalerta == '') {

  alert('Debes introducir un valor');
}

for (let i = 0; i < paresalerta; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    pares.push(i);
  }
}
document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML = pares;
```

```html
<div id="salida" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco qué quieres hacer con la variable pares ni por qué la evalúas en el `for` si solo se trata de un arreglo con una única cadena vaciá.

El `for` debería verse de la siguiente forma, evaluando la variable *paresalerta*:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < paresalerta; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(i)
    // document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML = pares;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer de la siguiente manera. Primero hay que calcular la mitad del número ingresado.

Usando `Math.floor` se asegura de que el resultado es un entero:

```
Math.floor(prompt(`Indica hasta que número quieres ver : `)/2)
```

Entonces, se crea un array con la mitad de la longitud ingresada:

```
[...Array(ingresado/2)]
```

El array será mostrado en el `div` con `id="salida"`:

```
document.querySelector("#salida").innerHTML = [...Array(/**/)] // ...
```

Luego se lo puede iterar con `map`, usando una variable que está fuera de la iteración, que llamamos `i`. Se va sumando de a 2.

```
.map(x=>i+=2).join(" ")
```

Como se suma de a 2, si la variable `i` empieza en 0, el primero será 2... Para que el primero sea 0, la variable `i` tiene que ser -2.

```
var i = -2
```

Para convertir la entrada de string a número, se pone un `+` a la izquierda. Además, como `i` es -2, hay que ajustar la longitud, sumando 2.

```
(2+ +prompt(`Indica hasta que número quieres ver : `))/2
```

Código completo:

```js
var i = -2
document.querySelector("#salida").innerHTML = [...Array(
  Math.floor(
    (2+ +prompt(`Indica hasta que número quieres ver : `))/2
  )
)].map(x=>i+=2).join(" ")
```

```html
<div id="salida" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que ya te respondieron, sólo me gustaría aportar otra forma de calcular números pares de manera recursiva:

```
function isEven(n) {
        //Utilizo abs por si ingresan un número negativo.
        n = Math.abs(n);
        if(n === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if(n === 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return isEven(n - 2);
            }
        }
  }
```

Además deberías pedir dos números: una cota inferior y una cota superior de manera que puedas visualizar los números en un rango `cotainferior <= n <= cotasuperior`.

```
 for(let i = cotainferior; i <= cotasuperior; i++) {
    if(isEven(i)) console.log(i);
  }
```

```js
function isEven(n) {
        //Utilizo abs por si ingresan un número negativo.
        n = Math.abs(n);
        if(n === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if(n === 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return isEven(n - 2);
            }
        }
  }

// Elegí los valores con prompt si querés.
let cotainferior = -50;
let cotasuperior = 50;

for(let i = cotainferior; i <= cotasuperior; i++) {
    if(isEven(i)) console.log(i);
}
```

Espero te sirva. Un saludo.